# Sagemaker Notebook instance very slow with tweepy api

Tags: machine-learning, tweepy, amazon-sagemaker, data-collection, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I collect tweets from file has more than 700,000 ids for tweets by using tweepy . Locally I have I7 processor and 16 GB ram and I make for loop on these ides to get the full text , geo , coordinates and place attributes.

And by using tqdm library ,It showed that 2.5 iteration done by second , that is very slow

[image]

After that I used sagemaker instances :
1 - ml.m5.4xlarge  = 64 GB ram    & 16 vCPU
2 - ml.m5.12xlarge  = 192 GB ram    & 48 vCPU

And the two instances gave me the same results also about 2.5 iteration per second , the same result , how could be ?

Then I used sagemaker studio lab which is free and give me 12 hours per day, it was fastest one it gave me about 6 iteration per second

[image]

> ```
> sample = anger['id'][:100000]
> tweets = []
> geos =[]
> coords =[]
> places =[]
> ids = []
> for i in tqdm(sample.index):
>     
>     id = sample[i]
>     # get the tweet
>     #ids.append(id)
>   
>     try:
>         status = api.get_status(id, tweet_mode='extended')
>         text = status._json['full_text']
>         geo = status.geo
>         coordinates = status.coordinates
>         place = status.place
>         
>         ids.append(id)
>         tweets.append(text)
>         geos.append(geo)
>         coords.append(coordinates)
>         places.append(place)
>         
>     except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e:
>         #print(i)
>         pass
> ```
>
> ## creating a DataFrame

```
data = {
'id' : ids,    'text': tweets,    'geo': geos,    'coordinates': coords,    'places':places   } 

 anger_dataframe =pd.DataFrame(data)

anger_dataframe.to_csv('anger_dataframe.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

> Blockquote

**My First Question :** why the sagemaker instance with these resources give me the same results and not different from my local resource .
And also sagemaker studio lab give me about 6 iteration per second but it not enough for me ,I have 6 million ides to collect.

**Second Question :** Is there any enhancing in for loop to run faster .

Resources :

1- https://studiolab.sagemaker.aws/

2- https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/